# thinking-sphinx returning results that don't fit the criteria

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search, thinking-sphinx

I have a model `practice_test_result` for which I have defined the index as follows:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :practice_test_result, with: :active_record, delta: true do
  indexes [student.first_name, student.last_name], :as => :student_name

  set_property :min_infix_len => 1
end
```

Searching for test results returns unexpected results in some cases listed below:

```
> PracticeTestResult.search('x').map{|x| x.student.name }                                             
 => []
```

This is as per expectation, as none of the student names have 'x' in it.

```
> PracticeTestResult.search('p').map{|x| x.student.name } 
 => ["Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "David Doe", "Timothy Doe", "Jane Doe"]
```

This is not expected, as none of the student names have 'p' in it.

```
> PracticeTestResult.search('ti').map{|x| x.student.name }
 => ["Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "David Doe", "Timothy Doe", "Jane Doe"]
```

Again not as per expectation; should have only one value `Timothy Doe` returned.

```
> PracticeTestResult.search('tim').map{|x| x.student.name }
 => ["Timothy Doe"]
```

Works as expected.

Any suggestion on how to debug this? Could this be because min_infix_len is set too low at 1?

Sphinx version : `Sphinx 2.1.7-release (rel21-r4638)`

Thinking-Sphinx version : `3.1.1`

Database : MySql

Rails version: `3.2.13`

Comment: Does PracticeTestResult have a `type` column? Are you using STI?

Comment: Thanks @pat! PracticeTestResult does have a `type` column, and the column does not hold any values in it. The `Student` model is a STI from `Person` model.

Comment: Trying with [field conditions](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#conditions) - for e.g.:  `PracticeTestResult.search({conditions: {student_name: 'd'}}).map{|x| x.student.name }` gives correct results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're facing is a scenario that only occurs when you have the inheritance column (which is named `type` by default) in your model (whether or not you're using it for STI - Thinking Sphinx can't figure that out).

To allow for querying across certain subclasses of the STI hierarchy, Thinking Sphinx adds a field called `sphinx_internal_class_name` which is used to limit search results to certain models. In your case, it would contain `'PracticeTestResult'` - hence, `ti` and `p` return all objects.

The workaround, as you've found, is to limit your queries to specific fields.

It's also worth noting that in earlier versions of TS v3.0.x, this internal field was always present. Given it's only useful when STI is in play, it now doesn't get added unless necessary.